# Getting wrong X-axis value in Python graph using matplotlib

Tags: python

I am creating one graph using python matplotlib. But I am getting wrong `X-axis` value. Please check the code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import collections
import re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/passwordenter image description here@127.0.0.1/XE')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select salary,employee_id from hr.employees  where employee_id in(100,101)')
graphArray = []


for row in cur:
    startingInfo = str(row).replace(')','').replace('(','').replace('u\'','').replace("'","")
    splitInfo = startingInfo.split(',')
    graphArrayAppend = splitInfo[0]+','+splitInfo[1]
    print graphArrayAppend
    graphArray.append(graphArrayAppend)
    datestamp, value = np.loadtxt(graphArray,delimiter=', ', unpack=True)


plt.plot_date(datestamp, value, 'b-', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

Please refer the below picture for output:

[image: matlab output chart]

Comment: Please consider updating the post to add code blocks.

Comment: Have you changed somewhere in your code the x axis with `xlim()`? This turns off autoscaling, [according to the `matplotlib` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim)

Comment: I think xlim() is for setting the axis between maximum and minimum. But my issue is I am getting different value. I am getting the variable value 17000 and 24000 for x-axis but in the graph, I am getting absurd value.

Comment: I strongly recommend using bind variables instead of hard coding the employee IDs in the WHERE clause. See section 4 of https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/tutorial/Python-and-Oracle-Database-12c-Scripting-for-the-Future.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong plot for this operation or maybe I don't understand your code enough... But try this.

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/passwordenter image description here@127.0.0.1/XE')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select salary,employee_id from hr.employees  where employee_id in(100,101)')
```

*just use 2 arrays because in your code you are going to append them to split them after!*

```
ar_salary = []
ar_emplID = []

for row in range(cur):
    startingInfo = str(cur[row]).replace(')','').replace('(','').replace('u\'','').replace("'","")
    splitInfo = startingInfo.split(',')
    ar_salary.append(splitInfo[0])
    ar_emplID.append(splitInfo[1])
```

*And instead of using the plot_date just use plot.*

```
plt.plot(ar_salary, ar_emplID, 'b-', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

This is how you want it but...

Word on advise:

If you are going to add an other employer with sal 21000.0 and id 103 the your plot is going to look like this:[image]

and I think you want more something like this: [image]

and that you do by changing the possition of your x axis with your y axis:

```
    plt.plot(ar_emplID, ar_salary, 'b-', linewidth=2)
```

***EDIT:***

The np.loadtxt is used for loading text from an textfile so it has no use for you.

Comment: Thanks actually the issue was with plt.plot_date. Actually, I was required to use plt.plot. Thanks for debugging the code.